# Relacion UnoAMuchos Symfony (Extraccion de datos)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, symfony4

Soy nuevo en Symfony y en general en programación PHP y me ha surgido un problema en un proyecto que estoy realizando.

Estoy haciendo un mini proyecto para gestionar contrataciones de una empresa.
Dichas contrataciones pueden tener varias alertas anexadas.

En mi BBDD tengo dos tablas creadas, una de Contrataciones y otra de Alertas con sus campos y además un campo id para contrataciones dentro de Alertas. 
Dejo una imagen para que se pueda ver mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo hecha una relación Uno A Muchos(Ya que cada contratación puede tener varias alertas, pero no al revés). Tengo correctamente todas las entidades en symfony y los Setters y Getters hechos.
El problema me surge cuando intento relacionar entre ellos las Contrataciones y las Alertas.

Tengo ya varias contrataciones creadas y les he puesto un botón a cada una de las contrataciones para añadir alertas. Pero no consigo rellenar el campo contratacio_id(Alertas) con la ID de Contrataciones pertinente. 
Lo he intentado hacer pasando y recogiendo la ID por GET, pero no me dice que el formato que le paso no es el correcto(aún pasandole un INT).

Adjunto la fución:

```
public function addAlerta(Request $request)
{

 $contractacioid=$request->query->get('id');
 $int = (int)$contractacioid;

 //var_dump($int);


    $alerta = new Alertes();
    $form = $this->createForm(AlertesType::class, $alerta);
    $form->handleRequest($request);



    if ($form->isSubmitted()){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $alerta->setContractacio($int);
        $em->persist($alerta);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('view_alertes');
    }



    return $this->render('alertes/addAlerta.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form -> createView()
    ]);
}
```

No se de que otra forma podría hacerlo. Espero haberme explicado correctamente...
Gracias de antemano

Comment: has ejecutado `bin/console doctrine:schema:validate` para estar seguro de que las relaciones estan correctas?

Comment: Intenta pegar las entidades que se relaccionan entre ellas, aunque sea el campo, por ver que todo este correcto.

Comment: Acabo de ver, que estas intentando asígnar un id, cuando Doctrine trabaja con entidades. Te lo escribo en respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando creas las relacciones entre las entidades, a nivel de symfony se trabaja con Objetos, por lo que no le tienes que pasar un ID, si no el objeto correspondiente a ese id.

Dando por hecho que el id que le pasas es correcto y es un int, tendrías que:

Tendrás que añadir con un "use" la clase contractacio

```
$er = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Contractacio::class);
```

Y con esto, el Entity Repositori (er) ya puedes buscar el objeto correspondiente. 
Como lo buscamos por id, valdría con pones simplemente find:

```
$contractacio = $er->find($int);
```

Una vez tengas la $contractacio la puedes añadir al object alerta con el set.

```
$alerta->setContractacio($contractacio);
```

Y ya la tendrías añadida.

Si la $contractacio con ese id no existiera, el método find, te devolvera un "null", estaría bien que lo tuvieras en cuenta a la hora de añadirlo.

Podrías comprobarlo con un isset:

```
if (isset($contractacio) {
    $alerta->setContractacio($contractacio);
else {
    throw new \Exception("la contractació no existe");
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: En primer lugar, muchas gracias por la respuesta. Efectivamente es lo que necesitaba. Como tu dices, estaba enfocando mal la manera de trabajar de Symfony. De nuevo gracias por tu tiempo.